# Content Deployment HA

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-deployment

Is that possible to add another application server to our SharePoint 2013 farm and make the content deployment HA(High Availability)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is any OOTB / automatic configuration for HA arch for the content deployment.

As only one CA server can be configured to accept CD Jobs, so you cant configure on both. You have to manually failover once things down.

Comment: Thanks, but what if we have CA running on more than one server in the farm?